# Change of product of functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When we think of deriving (naively) the derivative of the product of functions we can think of the following. Consider change of function product $\Delta (fg)$. If we change $x$ by $h$ tt follows:

$$
\Delta (fg)(x,h) = f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x) = \Big[f(x)+\Delta f(x,h)\Big] \Big[ g(x)+\Delta g(x,h) \Big]-f(x)g(x) = ... = f \Delta g + g \Delta f + \Delta f \Delta g
$$

In last line I omitted $(x)$ etc. More of less obvious. My question is there any intuitive explanation for this formula? Any graphical intuitive 'derivation' etc. With many thanks.

EDIT. I forgot $\Delta f \Delta g$ term. Now it is corrected. But believe this term is going to be so small it will vanish later when putting this into derivative definition. It that correct?

Comment: You can visualize this by moving up a dimension: rather than $h(t) = f(t)g(t)$ consider instead the function $u(t, r) = f(t)g(r)$. The graph of this function is a surface in 3-dimensional space and your original function will in a sense be a curve on this surface. You can now find the slope of a tangent line to this curve using some geometry and relate this to the product rule.

Comment: There is a 3blue1brown youtube video with nice visualizations (https://youtu.be/YG15m2VwSjA?t=258)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a rectangle with side lengths $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  If we change the length of each side by some incremental quantity $\Delta x$, then the change in the area of the rectangle is exactly what you wrote.